# Paging in ASP.net MVC3 Razor using Bootstrap Template

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, pagination, twitter-bootstrap-3

In my ASP.Net MVC3 RAZOR project i have to implement tables to Get Employee Data.I am using Bootstrap CSS template .Here my  question is that how can i implement pagination .I have tried JQgrid before that ,its not working for me because Jquery in my template is conflicting with Jqgrid jquery.Now am using basic table in my template to display data.there i need to implement Pagination

My Table View

```
<h2>ViewEmployeeData</h2>

<div class="main-container">
                <div class="container">
 <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="box-widget">
                                <table class="table data-tbl-boxy responsive">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                         <th>
                                           First Name
                                            </th>
                                            <th>
                                                Middle Name
                                            </th>
                                            <th>
                                                Last Name
                                            </th>
                                            <th>
                                                Age
                                            </th>
                                            <th>
                                                Date of Birth
                                            </th>
                                            <th>
                                                Address
                                            </th>
                                            <th>
                                                Position
                                            </th>
                                             <th>
                                                Department
                                            </th>
                                             <th>
                                                Date of Joining
                                            </th>
                                             <th>
                                                Educational Qualifications
                                            </th>
                                             <th>
                                                Experience
                                            </th>
                                             <th>
                                                Others
                                            </th>
                                            <th>
                                            Action
                                            </th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>

        <td>
            @item.FirstName
        </td>
        <td>
            @item.MiddleName
        </td>
        <td>
            @item.LastName
        </td>
        <td>
            @item.Age
        </td>
        <td>
            @String.Format("{0:d/M/yyyy}", item.DateOfBirth)
        </td>
        <td>
            @item.Address
        </td>
        <td>
            @item.Position
        </td>
        <td>
            @item.Department
        </td>
        <td>
            @String.Format("{0:d/M/yyyy}", item.DateOfJoining)
        </td>
        <td>
            @item.EducationalQuali
        </td>
        <td>
            @item.Experience
        </td>
        <td>
            @item.Others
        </td>
        <td>
         @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.EmpId }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.EmpId }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.EmpId })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="table-bottom clearfix"><div class="tbl-pagination pull-left"><div class="dataTables_paginate paging_bootstrap"><ul class="pagination"><li class="prev disabled"><a href="#">← Previous</a></li><li class="active"><a href="#">1</a></li><li><a href="#">2</a></li><li><a href="#">3</a></li><li><a href="#">4</a></li><li><a href="#">5</a></li><li class="next"><a href="#">Next → </a></li></ul></div></div><div class="tbl-data-info pull-right"><div class="dataTables_info" id="DataTables_Table_0_info">Showing 1 to 10 of 43 entries</div></div></div>
</div>
</div>



</div>
</div>
    </div>
```

My controller Code

```
 [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult ViewEmployeeData()
        {
            var data = Emp.EmpData.ToList();


            return View(data.ToList());
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `MVC4.Paging`,first install that via nuget package manager :

```
PM> Install-Package MVC4.Paging
```

[here](http://mvcpaging.apphb.com/) is example of that.

Comment: Hello Sirwan Affi..am using ASP.Net mvc3 ,can i use the same for MVC3

Comment: I'm not sure about supporting for MVC 3, but it seems that it supports